# Launch the .exe file using azure release pipeline in deployment group windows server using powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, command-line, pipeline

I am trying to launch the .exe file on deployment group server(windows server) using azure release pipeline with PowerShell script.
`Start-Process -FilePath "E:\Azure\test.exe"`
but I am unable to open the exe file on server and not any interface open on windows and no error showing in azure release pipeline.
I have also tried with command prompt but nothing happened.

I am trying to launch the exe file on deployment group server and open a interface in new window.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created an Azure Release Pipeline and configured a Deployment Group targeting a Windows Server, the PowerShell script to launch an .exe file would be:

Replace "C:\path\to\your\file.exe" with the actual path to your .exe file, and "/parameter1 value1 /parameter2 value2"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have already tried this but not solve this issue.